# Creating a for each loop on multitple letters using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

im working on an mobile web application, which uses data from a .jsp page in the same directory. I made it possible to get formdata and put it in a variable using jQuery's .val().

now i have created an array of the input, and want to loop it using the $.each.
Only problem is when i try to create the loop, it separates every letter, instead of words..

This is the code i wrote:

```
var entrylist= $('#entrylistForm').val (); 

/* gettin the formvalue. This looks like this:

[{s.ENTRYID=1480565, s.SHEETID=131444777, s.ENTRYDATE=2012-14-04}]

*/


$.each (entrylist, function (key, value) {
alert( key + "=>" + value+"");
    // ...
}
```

I'm tying to get the array like this:

```
[0]ENTRYID=1480565,
[1]SHEETID=131444777, etc...
```

help anyone, i cant figure out what i'm doing wrong..

thnx in advance!

Comment: is `[{s.ENTRYID=1480565, s.SHEETID=131444777, s.ENTRYDATE=2012-14-04}]` a string or object array?

Comment: try `$.param(formDataAsObject);`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the native .split function, and split by whitespace? Assuming the value is a string.

```
entrylist = entrylist.split(', ');
```

Comment: If '[{' and '}]' is part of the string, you'll want to use the replace method beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the split function.

```
var entrylist = $('#entrylistForm').val(); 
var list = str.split(', ');
```

Which would split it after ", " and put it into an array which you can access.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp